# EXPIRES in facebook - android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a question regarding these peices of codes

These are from facebook application using android.

```
 public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken()); /* Retrieve the OAuth 2.0 access token for API access: treat with care.*/
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook fb) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fb.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            fb.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return fb.isSessionValid();
        }
```

I want to know what is the importance of the variable EXPIRE ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very imported. After token expire your app won't be able to connect to facebook user account. Try to use offline access token for mobile apps.

Comment: Offline access is depricated as I remember

Comment: what happens when the access token is null and the expires is 0 ??